# Length of drawer slides

Tags: brackets, drawers

I build a new cabinet that needs drawers. The front of face frame to the front of the back wall is 18.75".  I'm planning to build a 17" drawer to fit that space.  My problem is to determine what length of full extension drawer slides to purchase. Most slides are either 16" or 18".  Which ones should I purchase? Can the rear mounting bracket be extended?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.